# "The specified base path "/home/rui/catkin_ws" contains a package but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace" how can I fix it?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my root workspace is /home/rui/catkin_ws

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221538/%22the-specified-base-path-%22/home/rui/catkin_ws%22-contains-a-package-but-%22catkin_make%22-must-be-invoked-in-the-root-of-workspace%22-how-can-i-fix-it?/) by [ruiscf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25180/ruiscf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you have a problem with your workspace structure.

As the message tells, you should run `catkin_make` in workspace root folder. Your workspace should have a tree like this:

```
/home
  /rui
    /catkin_ws
      /build
      /devel
      /src
         /your_ros_package
         /your_other_rospackage
```

And in this tree you should run `catkin_make` in `catkin_ws` folder.

If problem persists you can try recreating your workspace following the guide: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10